# How to sort Realm result order by a list?

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

I fetch Realm objects named "DictObj" by list of property "index" like this:

```
NSArray *listIDs = @[@1000,@0,@100,@4];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"index IN %@",listIDs];
self.fetchedResults = [DictObj objectsInRealm:realm withPredicate:predicate];
```

I simply fetch results but it auto order by primary key "index", I want keep it order by "listIDs". So I create sortDescriptor and try custom sort it like below, but it crash with error: "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSSortDescriptor property]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x"

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"index" ascending:NO comparator:^NSComparisonResult(id  _Nonnull obj1, id  _Nonnull obj2) {
    NSNumber *num1 = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:(NSInteger)obj1];
    NSNumber *num2 = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:(NSInteger)obj2];
    NSInteger listIndex1 = [listIDs indexOfObject:num1];
    NSInteger listIndex2 = [listIDs indexOfObject:num2];

    return listIndex1 < listIndex2;
}];
self.fetchedResults = [[DictObj objectsInRealm:realm withPredicate:predicate] sortedResultsUsingDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];

//Model
@interface DictObj : RLMObject
@property NSInteger index;
@property NSString *name;
@end
```

**How to customize sort the result order by a list in Realm?**

Answer (score 4):

`-[RLMResults sortedResultsUsingDescriptors:]` takes an `NSArray<RLMSortDescriptor *>`. In your code you're passing an `NSArray<NSSortDescriptor *>`. `RLMSortDescriptor` and `NSSortDescriptor` are different classes with different interfaces, hence the exception you're seeing.

At present `RLMResults` can only be directly sorted by property value. In order to sort on computed orderings like you're after you'll need to populate an `NSArray` with the contents of the `RLMResults`, then sort on that. Adding support for this on `RLMResults` is being tracked in [issue #1265](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1265) on Realm's GitHub repository.

Comment: Thanks! Very sad when it only support sort by property. I hope it will update soon at least keep order in the case "IN list".